# minimum dominating set from a path

Tags: graph, adjacency-list

I'm facing a problem described as follows :

Example :
Giving a path :

[0]------**[1]**------[2]------**[3]**------[4]

give the minimum dominatig set of this path : the solution would be **[1]** and **[3]**

The path in my program is described as an Adjacency list ,so :

[0]--> [1]

[1]--> [0];[2]

[2]--> [1];3]

[3]--> [2];4]

[4]--> [3]

What would be the idea to get the list of those elements from the Adjacency list?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Algorithms_and_computational_complexity). Then try to implement one of the presented algorithms and if you're still stuck in the code development you can come back to SO stating the __specific__ problem.

Comment: thanks ; i alredy implemented some of those in Wikipedia , my question is about a specific thing , mds from a path.+ i'm looking only for idea from other point of view

Comment: MDS is computed from a graph, your "path" is a specific graph, so the same algorithms apply.

Comment: yes i can do that , but for a specific graph 'the path' there are a better way to solve the problem , i mean in polynomial time ; the algoritm described in your reference has an exponential complexity.

Comment: Okay, in that case just order the vertices `v` of the path (as they are traversed, this is simple) and then _one_ possible solution is given by `v[1::3] + (v[-1:] if len(v) % 3 == 1 else [])`.